# Exercise 1.3 in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> 1.3 Let $A = k[X,Y]/(XY)$. Show that any element of $A$ has a unique representation in the form
>   $$a+f(X)X+g(Y)Y\quad\text{with}\quad a\in k, f\in k[X],g\in k[Y].$$
>   How do you multiply two such elements?
>
> Prove that $A$ has exactly two minimal prime ideals. If possible, find ideals $I,J,K$ to contradict each of the following statements:
>   (a) $IJ = I\cap J$;
>   (b) $(I+J)(I\cap J) = IJ$;
>   (c) $I\cap(J+K) = (I\cap J)+(I\cap K)$.
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUiHK.png)

I have the following questions:

1. I suppose that $(x)$ and $(y)$ are two minimal prime ideals in $A$.
   How can I show that they are minimal and that there are no other
   minimal prime ideals. (How can I show that a prime ideal is minimal
   in general?)
2. I know that for any ring $R$ we have $(I+J)(I \cap J) \subseteq IJ$. For which $R$ it becomes an equality?
3. Is $(c)$ always true? I cannot find any counterexample

Comment: Please type out images so that others can find it. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: (c) Try $I=(x+y)$, $J=(x)$ and $K=(y)$. (All ideals are in $A$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to the first part 1. 
Let $P$ be a prime ideal then since $xy=0$ we have $xy\in P$ so $x\in P$ or $y\in P$. This shows minimality, it remains to show for example that $(x)$ is prime.

Let $f_1(x)x+g_1(y)$ and  $f_2(x)x+g_2(y)$ be two elements where $g_i(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$, maybe with constant term.
If $$(f_1(x)x+g_1(y))(f_2(x)x+g_2(y))\in (x)$$
then $$g_1(y)g_2(y)\in (x)$$
and this means that $g_1(y)g_2(y)=0$ and so $g_1(y)=0$ or $g_2(y)=0$.

In the former case, $$f_1(x)x+g_1(y)=f_1(x)x\in(x)$$
Thus $(x)$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

`for the rest:`
(2): Prüfer domain are what you are looking for; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain).
(3): You can find example for $I \cap (J+K) \neq I \cap J + I \cap K$ at the site; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524671/ideals-in-a-ring-satisfying-i-cap-jk-neq-i-cap-j-i-cap-k).

Comment: The exercise is intended to provide a counterexample for each assertion. This means that the OP has to find such ideals into the *given* ring.

Comment: OP says: "For *which R* it becomes an equality?"

Comment: I'm *obviously* referring to (c).